# Android first run service update

Tags: android, google-play, android-service

I have a service which is only run first time when the app is started. In that service I am scheduling a alarm to send notification every 30 mins.

Now I modified that service to send notification every 1 hr. And then uploaded it to play store.

Now, if the users are updating the app from play store. Will they receive notification every 30 mins or 1 hr? And if the interval is still 30 mins,  what is the workaround to this?

Comment: I was on a slow internet so I couldn't add all tags.

Comment: I guess there are lots of questions regarding the service. Have you tried to search on stack overflow regarding your issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the request code of the pending alarm then you can cancel the already initiated pending intent first. Like this,

```
public void cancelPendingIntent(Context mContext,int requestCode,Intent intent){
    try {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, requestCode, intent,0);
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then you can set the alarm again with new pending intent.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, requestCode, myIntent,0);

cancelPendingIntent(mContext,requestCode,myIntent);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(//Set your alarm here);
```